# Найти год в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
def find_years(text: str) -> list:
    """
    Учитывая текст строки, вернуть список всех 4-значных чисел (годов) в этой строке.

     Годами здесь считаются только четырехзначные числа.
     Если есть 5-значное число, то это не считается годом,
     и не даст два года. Таким образом, вы не можете разделить их.

     Годы должны быть найдены с помощью регулярного выражения.

     Подсказка: используйте просмотр назад и просмотр вперед, чтобы проверить, что идет до и после чисел.

     :param text: заданная строка для поиска лет от
     :return: список лет (целых чисел), найденных в данной строке
    """
    result = re.findall(r"[0-9]{4}", text)
    return result

print(find_years("1998sef672387fh3f87fh83777f777f7777f73wfj893w8938434343"))
    # [1998, 7777]
```

при запуске кода выходит такой ответ `['1998', '6723', '8377', '7777', '8938', '4343']`
. Как изменить, чтобы он выписывал только 4 значные числа?

Comment: Вам нужно добавить условие, что символы слева и справа от этих четырех цифр не являются цифрами, но могут быть началом/концом строки.

Comment: как это сделать? Смотрела на данные возможности, но не выходит ?=foo
?<=foo
?!foo
?<!foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводит только 4 значные числа из строки:

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

Comment: Вам помог мой ответ?

Comment: огромное спасибо, только возникает такая ошибка AssertionError: assert ['1998', '1998', '7777', '1234'] == [1998, 1998, 7777, 1234]

Comment: Проверяю регулярку, возвращает такой ответ
match 2 place(s)：
1998
7777

Comment: `import re`

`txt = "1998sef672387fh3f87fh83777f777f7777f73wfj893w8938434343"`
`x = re.findall("(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)", txt)`

`print(x)`
Вот пример кода на Python

Comment: @Zaraza_21 AssertionError потому что в списке должны быть числа, а у вас строки. Конвертируйте строки в числа и все будет ок.

Comment: прекрасно, тоесть нужно поменять формат, который получается проходя по формуле на int. Но пробовала это сделать и он выдает ошибку, что данное выражение невозможно перевести в int

Comment: @Zaraza_21 ну попробуйте другим способом

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)', text)
ints = []
for element in result:
    ints.append(int(element))
return ints
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
txt = "1998sef672387fh3f87fh83777f777f7777f73wfj893w8938434343" 
x = re.findall("(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)", txt) 
ints = []
for element in x:
    ints.append(int(element))
print(ints)
```

Проверил код на сайте https://replit.com/languages/python3 все работает.
Не забывайте импортировать библиотеку

```
import re
```

Comment: вы этот код списали из другого ответа? один в один практически

Comment: Да, человек попросил подробнее, поэтому я ему его описал подробно